# Do commercial aircraft carry personal weapons?

Tags: safety, commercial-aviation

Even though airport security is very strong nowadays, commercial flights are still at risk of hijacking. Alternatively, passengers (perhaps mentally distressed) could provoke damage to crew, passengers or infrastructure.

Do commercial aircraft carry personal weapons for their crew to use? This could be either fire arms or non-lethal weapons (like batons, pepper spray, Taser, etc). On the one hand, it makes sense they do carry some form of deterrent. On the other hand, in the wrong hands these weapons could create more danger than if not present. Do we know something about this?

Online I read about planes carrying an [axe](https://www.express.co.uk/travel/articles/856844/flights-secret-plane-axe-cockpit), but this is not much of a deterrent since it is quite hard to use properly and effectively (I imagine). There is an old discussion [here](https://www.ainonline.com/aviation-news/aviation-international-news/2007-01-30/guns-cockpit) in the US context, which might suggest this is an ongoing debate.

PD: perhaps a firearm shot could affect the fuselage and put the whole aircraft at risk, so non-lethal weapons would make more sense.

PD2: this Q is broader than the suggested duplicates. It is not only about pilots. The existing answer confirms its broader nature.

Comment: which legislation are you asking about?

Comment: @Federico Sorry, the Q is general. I imagine answers could depend on jurisdiction, which is in itself interesting. Do not want to restrict scope _ex ante_

Comment: The second article you linked is your answer (at least for US). The [Federal Flight Deck Officer](https://www.tsa.gov/for-industry/training) program exists (and is not an ongoing debate as you say), so there are armed pilots on US airline flights.

Comment: @mins useful or not, many countries seem to think it worthwhile: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sky_marshal

Comment: @Jamiec: This is different, police officers in the cabin, not armed crews. But you have a point.

Comment: Well, question never really specified. "Do commercial aircraft carry weapons for the crew?" simple answer: "Yes, concealed with a crewmember trained on how to use it". The fact is no airline or country really publicises many details.

Comment: "*perhaps a firearm shot could affect the fuselage*", it's unlikely this would be disastrous, but as soon as there is a weapon aboard, it might also be used by criminals if they can seize it. The main problem is here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are pilots armed?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2761/are-pilots-armed) See also [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/3268/62).

Comment: Cockpit crewmembers carrying handguns applies only to the US.  In any case, hijackings have largely stopped for two reasons: reinforced cockpit doors, and the knowledge by the pax that a hijacking is likely to result in death and they have nothing to lose by trying to overpower the hijackers. This has changed the entire dynamic because before 9-11 a hijacking was usually assumed to result in a diversion and landing somewhere, so passivity was the wise option.

Comment: Check this out... title of the video is, "An unruly Air Marshal forces emergency landing"  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=esZVVXXZaLc  Something to think about, how weapons around can cause troubles even if in the hands of trained professionals.  Everybody is human.

Comment: Many years ago there was research into mechanisms of having a sleeping gas added to the environment within the cabin in the event of a hostile takeover.  I'm not sure if that research ever led to the designs being implemented.

Comment: When I saw the title of this question, I thought for a moment of a sapient aircraft carrying personal weapons for _its own_ use.

Comment: Did you notice any old discussion in the US context could only be relevant to domestic, not international flights? Does that not change the scope of the Question?

Comment: The second amendment to the constitution of the United States reads-- "A well regulated Militia, being necessary to the security of a free State, the right of the people to keep and bear Arms, shall not be infringed."-- commercial aircraft are not "people", and therefore in the USA, airplanes do not have the automatic right to "carry" weapons, and are generally not allowed to do so.  Except in Texas, where anything goes.

Answer (score 11):

Many countries and/or airlines have a [sky marshall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sky_marshal) program where a specially-trained law enforcement (or possibly military) person is on board with weapons used in case of hijacking.

Some examples:

- United Kingdom aviation security is handled by SO18: https://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/uk_politics/2590309.stm although it is unclear whether SO18 do any more than patrol the ground at Heathrow & London City airport.
- US has the [Federal Air Marshall Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Air_Marshal_Service) which oversee the [Federal Flight Deck Officer (FFDO) Program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Flight_Deck_Officer)
- El-Al (Israel's flag carrier) has since its inauguration always carried armed personnel: https://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/world/americas/2097352.stm

It should be noted that every country and/or airline is pretty tight-lipped about whether they do or do not employ sky marshals, probably for fear of affecting the operational usefulness of such roles. I don't think we can know for sure exactly where armed personnel are onboard!

Comment: Should be said that BBC link is from 2003 and I don't think I've once heard about a UK "Sky Marshal" since. I'm sure they conduct specific intelligence-led operations, but I don't think the UK actually has a routine sky marshal program like the US does

Comment: @Dan Oh I agree, SO18 is only really responsible for protecting the airports at Heathrow and City. But once upon a time I think they may have considered putting armed marshalls on aircraft (and maybe they do - they just keep it secret)

Comment: Just to highlight the complexity of the legal matters: [Air Marshals: The Need for Legal Certainty](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/147637539.pdf), with quite surprising cases (e.g. El Al Flight 432 and Dawson's  Field)

Comment: Of course, the Brits keeping the confusion level _up_ about whether they have sky marshals or not helps keep certainty level _down_ for the bad guys. Thus adding a touch more uncertainty to the bad guys' hopes of success.

Comment: Another reason, especially on international flights, is that bringing those weapons into another jurisdiction may well break the law. By treaty exceptions can be negotiated for law enforcement agents and their weapons. But that won't work for airline employees.

Answer (score 6):

As of March 2009, some US commercial pilots were trained in the use of weapons and were allowed to have them on board

Source: https://www.factcheck.org/2009/03/guns-for-pilots/

The program started, not surprisingly, soon after 9/11
https://www.nytimes.com/2002/07/10/politics/house-passes-bill-to-allow-airline-pilots-to-carry-guns.html

It looks like it's still in force (from March 2018):
https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-43377461